# How to use Test Learners and Confusion Matrix through Orange (GUI)

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix, orange

I'm new to use Orange GUI. I test some data with old labels such as cluster ID. Then I use K-means clustering to generate new data with the new attribute produced by new labels of cluster ID. But the problem is I don't know how to operate on Orange GUI to evalute the clustering effect between old and new labels as follows:

> (1) Confusion matrix(GUI) cannot connect to output data of k-means
>   clustering directly. And I guess I need to train my data. But I don't
>   know how to train it and take the training data to compare with
>   labeled data to get Confusion matrix.
>
> (2) ROC(GUI) also cannot connect that. And I speculate that ROC may be
>   working if after Test Learners andConfusion matrix are working.

If you've used Orange(GUI), your help is my appreciated. I hope you can guide me how to handle these icons and connections for evaluting k-means clustering effect. Thank you!

If my description is poor, you can leave messages here and I'll check every day morning and evening. My nation adopts UTC +8 zone.

:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusion matrix and ROC analysis are widgets intended to analyze the results of the classification that come from a Test Learners widget. A typical schema for such evaluation is:

[image: Classifier evaluation and analysis]

Widgets for clustering can add a column with cluster labels to the data set, but there is no widget to turn such column into a predictor. With the current set of widgets there is no way to use unsupervised methods as learners, and hence no way to use widgets to analyze their results in classification evaluation setup.

Comment: Your guide dawned on me gradually and I'm grateful for your help professor. Furthermore after I scan your blog and please excuse me for my abrupt questions, could you provide  links of learning Orange course? I'm so expecting that content. Thanks.